# Connecting to existing database in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, android-sqlite

I try to use precreated database for my android app written in Kotlin, so in my databaseHelper class I tried to use the following code for that:

```kotlin
    override fun onCreate(db: SQLiteDatabase)
    {
        db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME,null,SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE)

    }
```

I thought this will worm, but I get the message `val cannot be reassigned`.

Then in the next methods, which are supposed to perform actions on database (execute all needed queries) I reffer to the database like that:

```kotlin
        val db = this.writableDatabase
        val cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null)
```

(or just with `db.execSQL(query)` if don't need the results of selection; of course `query` is a string with SQL query)

The point is how can I access the precreated database because when I would just create new "global" variable (in companion object?) then I would have to reffer to it in diffent way... at least I think so... well maybe using the line `val db = this.writableDatabase` also in onCreate would do, but wouldn't it connect just "localy"(as I overrwrite the refference for db in parameter by local variable) instead of putting this precreated database into what is returned by `this.writableDatabase`?

Edit:
Well I think I find a solution to how to connect to database here https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/how-to-use-pre-populated-sqlite-database-using-kotlin/8068 but it still leave me with one serious problem: how to include that database in AndroidStudio project (to have something to connect to).
I mean that include this database as part of an app (as one of its resources)

Comment: Parameters are [implicit `val`](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/function-parameters-are-val-not-var/897/40) in Kotlin, so you need to assign to a new `val` or return the db. You can do `db =` but could do `val newDB =`

Comment: But the point is that I want then (in other methods other way connecting do database wouldn't do any sense in my case) reffer to this let's say `newDB`. How to reffer it? Or maybe returning it will make it accesible like thid db in parameter, so by this.writableDatabase?

Comment: I find some solution, but still there is one problem I didn't precisely adressed at first - how to add a database to a project (see the edit)